# Trouble creating/opening Portable Library Project with Xamarin Studio for Windows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have some trouble creating and opening a C# Portable Library Project in Xamarin Studio for Windows.

**Opening existing Project**

This Project is part of a solution containing another Project (an Android Application) that I can read, modify and compile correctly.

See the attached image - sorry for the Italian language but I think it's clear anyway.
[image: Trouble Opening Existing Portable Library Project]

**Creating new Project**

I wonder why I can't read this kind of projects neither create them (I don't even have this option - see the attached image where I circled the option that I should have but I don't).

[image: Trouble Creating New Portable Library Project]

I am using Xamarin Studio 4.0.9 (build 12) on Windows 7 / 32 bit - trial version.
During the installation process the log gave no errors and installed everything (the complete package).

I will publish the same post in Xamarn Forum too - maybe you're faster here? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your trail is still active? I had a problem where my trail was not active, and i could not use another assemblie in my project, but i could still create an android application. Check in Tools -> Account for more info on your account status.

Comment: Yes I just activated it, I checked and it's still active.